# Why algebraic integer to power p not divisible by p for large prime p

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading **Transcendental number theory (Baker A)** and now going through Lindemann's theorem. In the proof, he claims that

$$l^{np}(p-1)!\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne i}}^n(\alpha_{i}-\alpha_{k})^{p}$$

is an algebraic integer divisible by $(p- 1)!$ but not by $p!$ if $p$ sufficiently large (p is prime),
where $l$ is integer such that $l\alpha$'s are algebraic integer and $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\}$ is complete set of conjugates.

I had tried using minimal polynomial but it seems not work because the algebraic integer varies with p. Can anyone give details about this?

Comment: Isn't the product related to the discriminant of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_i$? If $p$ is sufficiently large, it won't divide $l$ or this discriminant, so the claim is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $\beta_i:=l\alpha_i$ is an algebraic integer for all $i$, we can rewrite the expression to get
$$l^{np}(p-1)!\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne i}}^n(\alpha_{i}-\alpha_{k})^{p}
=l^p(p-1)!\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne i}}^n(\beta_{i}-\beta_{k})^{p},$$
which is clearly divisible by $(p-1)!$. Now for it *not* to be a multiple of $p!$ we need that the remaining factor
$$l^p\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne i}}^n(\beta_{i}-\beta_{k})^{p},$$
is not a multiple of $p$. Note that the discriminant of the number ring $\Bbb{Z}[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n]$ is given by
$$\Delta:=\Delta(\Bbb{Z}[\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n])=\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne i}}^n(\beta_{i}-\beta_{k}),$$
which is an integer (assuming that the $\beta_i$ are a complete set of conjugates *over $\Bbb{Z}$*). This shows that the remaining factor above divides the integer $(l\Delta)^p$, and this is clearly not a multiple of $p$ for sufficiently large $p$.